# Python Tkinter Help: OptionMenu returns only the first item from the drop-down menu when submit button clicked

Tags: python, tkinter, dataset, text-files, optionmenu

I am trying to code a program that will add movies from a movie index data set I am using. The full code isn't submitted below; just the relevant bits. I have successfully added each movie from the data set as an individual item on the dropdown menu (as can be seen through the for loop and `*moviesarray` in the `OptionMenu` line of code).

However, I am experiencing a big problem as when I am trying to write the value of `clicked.get()` to the text file I created; which serves as the user's watch list; only the first movie from the drop-down menu is printed in the file, regardless of what movie I have selected.

For instance, the "titles" column in the data set that I used for the menu options may be the following:

- Avatar
- Up
- Avengers
- Groundhog Day

With these options, Avatar is always printed in the text file; regardless of if I selected Up or any other movie.

I am unsure what to do as the `clicked.get()` in the submit button declaration seems fine to me.

I also have a second problem in that, the command I typed, `clicked.set("Select Movie")` has no effect and doesn't work as Avatar just appears as the default text on the drop-down menu before I click it.

```
df = pd.read_csv("movie_dataset.csv")

def startup():
    username= entrybox.get()
    isfilepresent = os.path.isfile(username)
    if isfilepresent == False:
        watchlist = open(username, 'w').close()
        new_file(username)

def add_to_watch_list(movie, username):
    watchlist=open(f"{username}.txt", "w+")
    contents = watchlist.read()
    if movie in contents:
        pass
    else:
        watchlist.write(movie)
        watchlist.close()
    
def add_movies(username):
    username=username
    addWindow = Toplevel(root)
    addWindow.title("New Window")  
    addWindow.geometry("300x100")
    clicked = StringVar(addWindow)
    clicked.set("Select Movie")
    moviesarray = []
    for i in range (0, len(df)):
        name = df["title"][i]
        moviesarray.append(name)
        #moviesarray.append(str(df.title.to_string(max_rows = 20, index=None)))  
    spacinglabel1 = Label(addWindow)
    spacinglabel1.grid(row=0,column =0)
    drop = OptionMenu(addWindow, clicked, *moviesarray)
    drop.grid(row=1,column=1)
    submitbutton= Button(addWindow, text = "Submit:", command = partial(add_to_watch_list, clicked.get(), username))
    submitbutton.grid(row=1,column=2)
    exit3 = Button(addWindow, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
    exit3.grid(row=1, column=7)
```

So in essence, I want the value selected from the `OptionMenu` to be passed to the `add_to_watch_list()` function when the submit button is pressed; instead of just the first value from the menu.

I also want the default value of the menu before being clicked, to say `"Select Movie"`
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: hint: `partial(add_to_watch_list, clicked.get(), username)` is the same as `value=clicked.get(); partial(add_to_watch_list, value, username)`.

Comment: It doesn't help :(